# Firebase DocumentSnapshot is always null

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the data of a document in Firebase. I am using this function:

```
DocumentSnapshot docRef = 
await Firestore.instance.collection("products").document("SF").get();

print(docRef.exists);
```

> docRef.exists returns "false" even if the document is exisiting for sure.

I think it has something to do with the auth flow and the system does not recognize the logged in user.

```
print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser());
```

results in Instance of 'Future < FirebaseUser>'.

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Best regards

**EDIT:**

Here are my rules from firebase:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you make `read` operation in security rules public, does it work then?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I edited my question. The rules are public.

Comment: can you use await like that, without async?

Comment: The await is in an async function:     data.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) async { .... })

Comment: I found a solution for the problem, but have another problem now... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652643/flutter-documentsnapshot-inconsistent I thought it had something to do with the document("SF") part, but it didn't. This thread can be closed.

Comment: If your read operation is not allowed, the read would **fail**. It won't give a non-existing snapshot. So the rules can't be the problem here. Can you clean up the code snippets to give a single, standalone piece of code that I can run to reproduce the problem, and then add a screenshot of the document you're trying to read?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I already solved the problem. It had nothing to do with the security rules. I opened another question. You already commented on that one ;) Thank you!

Comment: If you solved this problem, please post your solution as an answer so future visitors can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you define the security rules is not correct. Change your security rules.

```
match /products/{document=**}  { 
     allow read, write: if true;
 }
```

Comment: I changed the security rules, but now the app throws "PlatformException(Error performing getDocuments, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null)"

Comment: I updated my answer. Check and change your security rules. Now it will work

Comment: Still the same error... I will wait a few more minutes and try it again.