# Flutter DocumentSnapshot

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the data from a DocumentSnapshot from firebase.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('products').document("Lucius_Malfoys_Zauberstab").get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
          print(ds.exists);
        });
```

This method works totally fine and returns true, but:

```
      var keys =  ["Lucius_Malfoys_Zauberstab"];


     String id =  keys[0];
     print(id); ---> prints Lucius_Malfoys_Zauberstab


     Firestore.instance.collection('products').document(id).get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      print(ds.exists);
      });
```

returns false...

Does anyone have an idea, why this is the case?
It is just a small problem in my application, but I am curious why this happens. Just for understanding. Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Here is a screenshot of the cart collection:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the products collection:

[image]

Comment: We have no way of knowing what `data.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc)  {` is, so it's hard to say what's going wrong. Can you reproduce the problem with a hardcoded list of IDs, and if so, update the code in your question?

Comment: I added two screenshots of my firebase. Does this work for you or should I hardcode the list? Btw. I dont think the problem has something to do with the `data.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {` part.

Comment: If the problem is not related to the loop, reproduce it without the loop and update the question. If the problem is related to the loop, make sure we can reproduce the problem with only the code you provided. Using hard-coded values trump anything dynamic each time for this. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: OK I updated my question and removed unnecessary code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem. The best I can do at this point is show you what I've done:

[image]

The first print of `false` is before I had the document. I then created the document, ran `_test` again, and it printed `true`.

If I remove my permission on `/55652643/{document}`, the `print` statement isn't reached, and instead I get a stack trace that permission has been denied.

Comment: Ok, so it definitely has something to do with `var keys = doc["products"].keys.toList();` Thank you for your help!

Comment: Note that this is precisely why I asked for you to **reproduce** the problem without that. If you had run the code you shared, you should have gotten the same result I did.